# Can you remove the flash drive after installing ubuntu using a flash drive?

Tags: system-installation

I know that you install ubuntu using a flash drive so do u have keep in your computer to run Linux.

Comment: Indeed, after shutting down the PC you unplug the flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

After you have finished the installation to the harddisk, you will be asked to reboot. You can safely remove the USB flash drive after that reboot.